# Citing EU regulations using BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, natbib

For my dissertation, I would like to cite an [EU regulation No 269/2014](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1416170084502&uri=CELEX:32014R0269) using BibTeX in the APA style. Has anyone ever done this? What is the most convenient way to do so and which template should be used?

I am aware that there are specialised packages for citing legislation, but this is likely going to be the only legal source for my document.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
% Body text

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\nocite*{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your situation. It will be much easier for us to help when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It would be helpful if you could also specify what information needs to be included in the citation and how it should be formatted in the bibliography/text.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "APA style". Do you mean to you the `apacite` package and the `apacite` bibliography style? If not, what do you have in mind?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd treat it with the catch all `@misc` entry:

```
\documentclass{article}% no page break before bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{eu-269-2014,
  author={{Council of European Union}},
  title={Council regulation ({EU}) no 269/2014},
  year={2014},
  note={\newline\url{http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1416170084502&uri=CELEX:32014R0269}},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
% Body text
\citet{eu-269-2014}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apa}

\end{document}
```

Note that `filecontents` is used just for convenience; use your normal method with an external `.bib` file. I also changed the document class for avoiding page breaks.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

When I cite EU regulations, I use article, because the regulations or directives are published in the Official Journal. I'm not sure about the author, so I leave it blank.

```
@Article{eu03,
  title   = {REGULATION (EC) No 765/2008 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL of 9 July 2008 setting out the requirements for accreditation and market surveillance relating to the marketing of products and repealing Regulation (EEC) No 339/93},
  journal = {OJ},
  year    = {2008-08-13},
  volume  = {L 218},
  pages   = {30--47},
}
```

That renders to:

[image]

Comment: Why not @Article{GDPR16,
  title   = {Regulation (EU) 2016/679 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 27 April 2016 on the protection of natural persons with regard to the processing of personal data and on the free movement of such data, and repealing Directive 95/46/EC (General Data Protection Regulation)},
  journal = {Official Journal L110},
  year    = {2016-05-04},
  volume  = {59},
  author = {European~Union},
  pages   = {1--88},
}