# How to cite the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) IEEE style with BibTeX?

Tags: citing

The regulation can be found [here](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj).

I'm trying to cite it in IEEE style and include it in my .bib file but I can't seem to find the correct format for this. Is anyone aware how to cite it? Here is my citation template:

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[strings]{underscore}

\begin{document}

\IEEEPARstart{Y}{our} document here and just to cite: \cite*

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{mybib} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: `IEEEtran` (and most other bibliography styles for LaTeX for that matter) does not have extensive support for legal citations. So I'd take the `@misc` entry type and play around with the fields a bit to see what how you can make the output look OK. People in different fields may expect different levels of details for legal citations.

Comment: In section II.N you can find the IEEE guidelines for US legal documents: https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf, maybe you can try and model a similar output with `@misc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I cite European Union's General Data Protection Regulation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496100/how-should-i-cite-european-unions-general-data-protection-regulation)